# How to make Assembly in Xcode 5 shows ARM instructions?

Tags: ios, assembly, arm

Performing Assembly (Product -> Perform Action -> Assemble) in Xcode 5 shows i386 instructions.  How do I get ARM assembly code instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong here, but shouldn't all you have to do is change your active scheme from iOS Simulator to "iOS Device" and then regenerate the assembly.

[image]

Comment: @Boon Glad to hear it!